# Android getIntent gets old data instead on new one

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I am newbie in android app.I am developing a chat application.I have used a RecyclerView and inside recyclerview adapter i am passing one data on start of a activity

That is my code below

ChatAdapter.java
//MyViewHolder

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        TextView name;
        ImageView img,status;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            img= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            status=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position=getAdapterPosition();
            UsersList current=data.get(position);
            Intent intent=new Intent(context,ChatRoomActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("NAME",current.name);
            intent.putExtra("USERNAME",current.username);
            **Log.wtf("CAAAAA","USERNAME "+current.username);**
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Whenever i click on recycler view then it is passing correct data but when i press back button and clicks on recylclerview(other) then it is passing wrong data

I have checked via Log(Bold one),there correct data is shown but i dont know why wrong data is received in activity.
Please help me.Your response will be highly valuable for me

Comment: what is the code in ChatRoomActivity.java?

Comment: intentUsername=getIntent().getExtras().get("USERNAME").toString();

Comment: are you using `launchMode` other than `standard` for `ChatRoomActivity` in `manifest`?

Comment: try changing it to `intentUsername=getIntent().getExtraString("USERNAME");` And What is the type of `current.username` in `UsersList`

Comment: This is my manifest

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".ChatRoomActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: current.username is of String type

Answer (score 1):

```
getAdapterPosition()
```

Returns the Adapter position of the item represented by this ViewHolder.

> Note

that this might be different than the getLayoutPosition() if there are pending adapter updates but a new layout pass has not happened yet.
RecyclerView does not handle any adapter updates until the next layout traversal. This may create temporary inconsistencies between what user sees on the screen and what adapter contents have. This inconsistency is not important since it will be less than 16ms but it might be a problem if you want to use ViewHolder position to access the adapter. Sometimes, you may need to get the exact adapter position to do some actions in response to user events. In that case, you should use this method which will calculate the Adapter position of the ViewHolder.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution!! Actually the reason for old intent data is broadcast receiver.The broadcast receiver sends old data when activity is resumed.So therefore,we need to unregisted the broadcast receivers

Here's my code below

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(messageReceiver2);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(messageReceiver3);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(messageReceiver4);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME")` in Target activity.

EDIT :

```
UsersList current =new UsersList();
 current.name=getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME");
current.username=getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME");

new Thread(new Runnable() { (At)
Override public void run() { 
adapter=new ChatroomAdapter(ChatRoomActivity.this,dbHelperChatRoom.getMessages(current))‌​;

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
@Override public void run() 
{ recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); 
} }); } }).start();
```

Comment: Add log statement at target activity also and compare with it sender.

Comment: In log statement correct data is shown, but whenever i use that variable, it is interpreted with old value....In other words correct data is received but when used, (In chat view) it shows old data

Comment: new Thread(new Runnable() {
                (At)Override
                public void run() {
                    adapter=new ChatroomAdapter(ChatRoomActivity.this, dbHelperChatRoom.getMessages("_"+username+"_"+intentUsername));
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();

Comment: Add code for method dbHelperChatRoom.getMessages(""+username+""+intentUsername))‌​ and u should take all values from intent into model class and then you have to send to your method.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with getMessages.Only intentUsername has old value,due to that wrong operation is performed..

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Action Name for the activity in your manifest.

It should be `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />` rather than `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`

The docs for android.intent.action.MAIN state the following: Activity Action: means that this activity is the entry point of the application, i.e. when you launch the application, this activity is created, does not expect to receive data.